I'm trying to implement a delegate in c++, but I don't understand how to actually pass the delegate into a function
I'm trying to just use the code from this article: http://blog.coldflake.com/posts/C++-delegates-on-steroids/
So the delegate is this:
class Delegate
{
    typedef void (*Type)(void* callee, int);
public:
    Delegate(void* callee, Type function)
        : fpCallee(callee)
        , fpCallbackFunction(function) {}
    template <class T, void (T::*TMethod)(int)>
    static Delegate from_function(T* callee)
    {
        Delegate d(callee, &methodCaller<T, TMethod>);
        return d;
    }
    void operator()(int x) const
    {
        return (*fpCallbackFunction)(fpCallee, x);
    }
private:
    void* fpCallee;
    Type fpCallbackFunction;
    template <class T, void (T::*TMethod)(int)>
    static void methodCaller(void* callee, int x)
    {
        T* p = static_cast<T*>(callee);
        return (p->*TMethod)(x);
    }
};

And a class with the function I want to use is this:
class A
{
public:
    void foo(int x)
    {
        printf("foo called with x=%d\n", x);
    }
    void bar(int x) {}
};

And he shows how to use it here:
int main()
{
    A a;
    Delegate d = Delegate::from_function<A, &A::foo>(&a);
    d(42);
}

This works nicely, but the idea is to be able to actually pass this delegate into a function without any dependencies.
So if I have a new function that takes a string and prints it...
void printString(const std::string& str) {
    std::cout << str << std::endl;
}

How do I modify the parameters passed into this printString function so that it can take this delegate? What is the parameter type for the new delegate "d" that I made?
Something like...
void printString(const std::string& str, auto d) {
        std::cout << str << std::endl;
        // and then I can do something with d here
    }

So that I can then make main() this:
int main()
    {
        A a;
        Delegate d = Delegate::from_function<A, &A::foo>(&a);
        d(42);
        printString("foo", d(42));    <- note I don't know if I include the (42) here
    }

So the question is, what do I put as the parameters in printString so that I can pass d into it?

A side note: Is it only for education purposes ? In practice you can use std::function instead of your Delegate.

It is not clear what you are trying to achieve. If you want to pass the Delegate d as an argument to printString you can make the parameter Delegate const & d. But if you want to pass d(42) - it's the invokation of d, and it returns void so there's no point passing it anywhere.

You can't easily pass the Delegate with an included parameter to another function.
Note that with c++11 lambdas or std::bind/std::function the Delegate class isn't necessary:
int main()
    {
        A a;
        printString("foo", std::bind(&A::foo, a, 42));
        printString("foo", std::bind_front(&A::foo, a, 42));
        printString("foo", [&]{ a.foo(42); });
    }

If you do still want to use the Delegate class then these techniques still apply:
int main()
    {
        A a;
        Delegate d = Delegate::from_function<A, &A::foo>(&a);
        auto delegateOp = &Delegate::operator();
        printString("foo", std::bind(delegateOp, d, 42));
        printString("foo", std::bind_front(delegateOp, d, 42));
        printString("foo", [&]{ d(42); });
    }

https://godbolt.org/z/rzohE4Knj
